# Oracle, trigger to control link between tables

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to create a trigger to control a link between tables. I have the following table structure (image below). an item is linked to a budget and a structure, and this structure should be linked to the same budget.
Sometimes the item receive wrong structures, receive structures different from its own budget budget. I need that when you insert a budget item or edit a budget item to be validated if the id_budget are equal, the id_budget of dg_budget_item is equal to the id_budget dg_budget_structure to which it is being linked

[image]

I started building this trigger, but do not know how to continue

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_BUDGETO_STRUCTURE_ITEM_ID_STRUCTURE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF id_budget_structure ON dg_budget_structure_item
  select id_budget from dg_budget_structure where id_budget_structure = new.id_budget_structure      
  FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (new.id_budget <> ???(result of select?))
  pl/sql_block
```

Comment: From all that you say here, structure should be a field of budget table and remove the fk for structure from the item table. There is no need for the structure table.

Comment: Hi.
No man, you are reversing the logic. I have several budgets every budget has several structures (costs, revenues, services, etc.) and within these structures are the items that are financial accounts.

When importing month financial accounts to the system, it does not always know which structure it must be created (a new account for example) and sometimes it is created in a wrong account or wrongly reclassified by the user. So I need to validate the id_budget between the two tables

Comment: What do you want it to do if they are not equal?

Comment: stop running, rollback and then I will deal with in the code an alert to this

Comment: @devi: FYI: in your diagram, your little "crows feet" are backwards. For example, your link between `dg_budget_item` and `dg_budget` shows a 1 to many relationship, with 1 budget item having many budgets. However, the actual FK/PK definitions are backwards to that. In other words, in `dg_budget_item`, you have a FK on `id_budget` to the `dg_budget` table, which would be unique with it's `PK`, so it should be, 1 budget has many budget items.  ;)   (same with the other 2 links you show). Doesn't really change things, but a bit misleading ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close to what you want

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_BUDGET_STRUCTURE_ITEM_ID_STRUCTURE
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF id_budget_structure ON dg_budget_item
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_id_budget_structure   NUMBER;
   Budgets_do_not_match    EXCEPTION;
   v_code                  NUMBER;
   v_errm                  VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
   SELECT id_budget INTO v_id_budget_structure FROM dg_budget_structure WHERE id_budget_structure = :new.id_budget_structure      
   IF :new.id_budget <> v_id_budget_structure THEN
      RAISE Budgets_do_not_match;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN Budgets_do_not_match THEN
      Raise_application_error (-20001,
         'Budget '||TO_CHAR(:new.id_budget)||' for structure '
         || :new.id_budget_structure || 'does not match the budget trying to be linked';
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      Raise_application_error(-20002,
         'Invalid budget structure ' ||:new.id_budget_structure);
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_code := SQLCODE;
      v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 64);
      Raise_application_error(-20000,
         'Unexpected error ' || v_code  ': ' || v_errm;
END;
```

You cannot `ROLLBACK` within a trigger so your application will need to deal with that.

Comment: No problem. Was good to get back into some Oracle code. FYI, you can change the error numbers it reports, of course, but must be -20000 to -20999. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329 for more info.